# Unknown div Checkdv_1 & checkfr_1 is rendering on load of webpage

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, frontend

I don't know from where div with containing `id='checkdv_1'` is rendering. It happens only while loading or refreshing a webpage.

Due to this I've to click twice on the screen to access content of the screen or if I deletes this div using web dev tools can access smoothly webpage screen content.

Structure of this is :

```
<div id="checkdv_1"...>
  <iframe id='checkfr_1'...>
     Other stuffs
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Note: it happens only in chrome.

Thanks in advance.

[image: checkdv_1 error 1]

[image: error 2]

Comment: Your question is how to remove it in javaScript?

Comment: Nope it's not about javascript.. It happens only in chrome at the time of loading any webpage

Answer (score 1):

You might have installed an extension called "Live color picker". I was facing the same issue and I found that to be the culprit. Please try disabling/removing the extension and the problem should be solved for you.